# How to retrieve the recent files used by all app in windows

Tags: java, windows

I want to find out the recent file used by all applications in windows env using java. 
I have tried with

1. using Registry: I am trying to get the recent file information from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSavePidlMRU. But I am getting some "HEX" value but i am not able to retrive the string equivalent. I have also tried  http://code.google.com/p/java-registry/
2. I have also tried with "recent" file folder. But i am not able get the actual type/path of the file.

Comment: If you say "recent", what is the time interval of the files/folders created/edited is considered as recent files?

Comment: Thanks Kaipa for your quick reply, actally i am interested with the file open/closed by the user for his current login session.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for Sysinternal's [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (by now, that's official - and free - Microsoft software). First, add a filter of type process name of value "java.exe" like this, then add the "ReadFile" and "WriteFile" operations as additional filters, like this:

[image: Process Monitor Filter Editor Screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sry, i might not be clear enough... I want to perform this programmatically using java.